# Is is still proper to include the @param varname in a PHP docblock?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, docblocks

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock_Description_Details) the format for `@param` docblock parameters is `type [$varname] description` where `$varname` is optional. This seems to be backed by the phpDocumentor project [which states](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html):

> ```
> @param datatype $paramname description
> @param datatype1|datatype2 $paramname description
> ```
>
> NOTE: as of 0.4.1, @param can document phpdoc.de-style, with optional $paramname

So is it still proper form to include the $paramname or should it be left out?

```
/**
 * Have a foo!
 *
 * @param string $foo is a string
 * @param string This is another string
 * @return string
 */
function haveAFoo($foo, $bar) { ... }
```

Comment: I would go with the actual software's (phpDocumenter) documentation over wikipedias.

Comment: Well, while don't see any conflict between them, phpDocumentor is based on the docblock standard, so wikipedia is probably more important than the phpDoc implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More "proper form" would be to include $paramname.  It ensures zero ambiguity in matching the @param line with its matching argument in the function signature.  It is very likely listed as "optional" only as as old backwards-compatibility issue with "phpdoc.de style".  I doubt that this optional handling remains available in phpDocumentor2.

Comment: [Seems you are right](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/tags/param.html) as `"Note phpDocumentor supports @param tags which omit the name, this is NOT RECOMMENDED but provided for compatibility with existing projects."`